# How to change data of Main Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, fragment

I Have fragment 1, fragment 2, fragment 3 which are in the Main Activity. there is a TextView in the main Activity, how can the fragments change the text in the text view?

I already did the casting  (Actvity).getActivity but i don't want my app to have error when changing Activities

Comment: [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) in the same way you can update main activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a setter method like `setTextViewText(String str)` in the activity and from fragment call the method like `((YourActivity)getActivity()).setTexrViewText(str)`

Comment: But doesn't that make your fragment dependant on a specific activity? The fragment would crash if used in another activity.

Comment: @Kusan...You are correct. In that case you can use "instanceof" operator to compare the instances.