# Android Studio Kotlin - Change EditText text from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I need to edit a `editText` which is on `main_layout` from a fragment instead of `MainActivity()`.
I've tried inflating main_layout to fragment but that doesn't worked (`editText` doesn't change), then I've tried to create method

```
 fun changeEditText(){
    editText.setText(R.string.name)
}
```

but when I call it in my Fragment using

```
MainActivity().changeEditText()
```

it gives me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

How can I edit this `editText` from fragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change data of Main Activity from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405335/how-to-change-data-of-main-activity-from-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize an activity via its constructors. You can call the method from fragment like below

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeEditText();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getActivity()` from the Fragment to get a reference to its parent activity:

```
(activity as? MainActivity)?.changeEditText()
```

However, a better approach would be to use a listener so the fragment doesn't care what it's parent activity has implemented:

```
interface Listener {
    fun onTextChanged()
}

fun changeEditText() {
    editText.setText(R.string.name)
    listener?.onTextChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //override ......

    fun changeText() {
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext)
        edittext.text = "something"
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var hostActivity: AppCompatActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context){
        hostActivity = context as AppCompatActivity
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(){
        hostActivity.changeText()
    }
}
```

Or

```
class MainActivity :AppCompatActivity(), MyCallback() {
    // override ......

    override fun onTextChange(){
        val editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext)
        edittext.text = "something"
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var myCallback: MyCallback

    override fun onAttach(context: Context){
        myCallback = context as MyCallback
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(){
        myCallback.onTextChange()
    }
}

interface MyCallback {
    fun onTextChange()
}
```

Or

```
class MainActivity :AppCompatActivity(), MyCallback() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        val sharedViewmodel = ViewmodelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class)
        sharedViewmodel.text.observe(this, object: Observer<String> {
            override fun onChanged(text: String?){
                val editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext)
                edittext.text = text
            }
        })
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var hostActivity: AppCompatActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context){
        hostActivity = context as AppCompatActivity
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(){
        val sharedViewmodel = ViewmodelProviders.of(hostActivity).get(SharedViewModel.class)
        sharedViewmodel.text = "My new text"
    }
}

class sharedViewModel: ViewModel(){
    private val textHolderLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getText(): LiveData<String> {
        return textHolderLiveData
    }

    fun setText(text: String) {
        textHolderLiveData.value = text
    }
}
```